# GWT SSL + Jetty + Same origin policy = confusion

Tags: gwt, same-origin-policy, embedded-jetty

I am using GWT and want to enable SSL on one html page(module). I have multiple modules and one such module is secured with following configuration in my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/Secure.html</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I have another module (a login page), from which I call Secure.html to pass users' login information over SSL. I have following questions:

1. Am I violating same origin policy by calling Secure.html module from http (the non secured login page)?
2. How do I add a connector for SSL in the embedded jetty? I am using GWT eclipse plugin. I hate it though. When I try to access the secured Secure.html page, I get 403 - forbidden in dev mode. I don't want to use SSL for all my modules (`-server :ssl`). But if I deploy the app on an external server tomcat, it works fine.
3. Am I doing it right? Must be better approach than this?

Answer (score 1):

1) You're definitely violating [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) by changing the protocol.

2) You don't need to have the connector for the embedded Jetty...what you see there is (and should be) identical to what you'd see over HTTPS. SSL is a matter of putting your content behind a secure server. IMO this is a production concern, not a development concern.

Comment: But it's a different HTML page. Still?

Comment: How will I enable a SSL port in the embedded jetty? I don't want to change the GWT jetty launcher file. So the question is, how do I secure a one resource (a HTML file) with SSL in the GWT dev mode without opening the SSL port in the embedded jetty?

Comment: Okay. Pardon me for my ignorance here on SOP. how people call an https page from http? Meanwhile I'll go through the policy.

Comment: You'd use URL rewriting to send the user to `https://myserver.com/login.html` as soon as they hit your insecure login page `http://myserver.com/login.html`.

Comment: Okay. I wanna do something like:
1. From http://myserver.com/login.html, when users click on login button, I want to send request to a resource(an HTML page or a servlet) which is secured with SSL on the server. So that the users' credentials will go over SSL.
2. After authentication, sever will redirect the request to an non secured http page.

Comment: You're missing the big point here: your insecure page cannot know that the user has been successfully authenticated by a different host due to the Same-Origin Policy. What you're trying to do isn't going to happen.

Comment: Chris, Something similar to facebook login?